# Where is there a munach legarmei before a kadma?

Tags: trop-cantillation

On the side of Shemini 10:6, the blue Tikkun Simanim quotes the mesorah that there are three places where a munach legarmei is before a mahpach: there, Emor 21:10, and Rut 1:2.

Then it says (in parentheses, not part of the quote from the mesorah):

> ושאר יבאו לפני רביע או קדמא שלפני דרגא ואזלא

While munach legarmei before revii is very common, I don't remember ever seeing one before a kadma.  According to the note, there must be at least two somewhere in Tanach.  Where are they?

Comment: For future reference: http://quantifiedcantillation.nl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you've probably seen before is [Genesis 28:9](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.9).

The others are scattered in more obscure parts of Nakh: [Samuel 1:14:3](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.14.3) [Samuel 1:14:47](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.14.47) [Samuel 2:13:32](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.13.32) [Kings 2:18:17](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.18.17) [Isaiah 36:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.36.2) [Jeremiah 4:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.4.19) [Jeremiah 38:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.38.11) [Jeremiah 40:11](http://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.40.11) [Ezekiel 9:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.9.2) [Haggai 2:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Haggai.2.12) [Chronicles 2:26:15](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.26.15).

It also happens twice before a Pazeir: [Daniyel 3:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.3.2) [Nehemiah 8:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Nehemiah.8.7).

Comment: Ah right, I do remember the one in Toldot now

Comment: The Tanach Simanim, consistently with this note in their Tikkun, prints the ones before the pazeirim as psikim.  How do we in general tell the difference between a munach legarmei and a regular munach psik?  Is it a mesora, and you're quoting a different one than the simanim uses?  Or is it derived from the logic of the sentence?  If it's the second I have no idea what the reason is in Nechemia, it's a list of names and we have no information about how to group them that's not contained directly in the pesukim.

Comment: @Heshy Nechemiah is the easy one as there is a Merkha which is the Meshareit of Munach-Legarmeih. If it was a regular Psik there we'd get the regular Meshareit of Pazeir which is many regular Munachs.

Comment: @Heshy In general yes it's just Mesorah (old manuscripts have Mesorah lists of every regular Psik in Tanakh), but, to somewhat oversimplify things, you can usually spot them by the Merkha before or by the unexpected position in the verse.

Comment: what about in Behaalotcha 9:10?  כי-יהיה has a mercha but טמא wouldn't make sense with a munach legarmei, דרך רחוקה isn't a kind of tumah (except _maybe_ metaphorically in that טומאה~עבירה and you're not doing a mitzva designated for that time - but it's a stretch, especially if you're on דרך רחוקה due to אונס).

Comment: There is no merkha there [in accurate texts](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%98_%D7%99). Yihyeh has a meteg and is attached to Tamei. Someone once mistook the meteg for a merkha and separated the words in some printings. (Kudos though for realizing to ask!)