History of the name Shabsai
The earliest mention of the name שבתי that I found is in Nehemiah 8:7

וְיֵשׁ֡וּעַ וּבָנִ֡י וְשֵׁרֵ֥בְיָ֣ה ׀ יָמִ֡ין עַקּ֡וּב שַׁבְּתַ֣י ׀ הֽוֹדִיָּ֡ה מַעֲשֵׂיָ֡ה קְלִיטָ֣א עֲזַרְיָה֩ יוֹזָבָ֨ד חָנָ֤ן פְּלָאיָה֙ וְהַלְוִיִּ֔ם מְבִינִ֥ים אֶת־הָעָ֖ם לַתּוֹרָ֑ה וְהָעָ֖ם עַל־עׇמְדָֽם׃

What does the name mean? And who is this person שבתי?

It could also be found in Psalms 27:4, where the word means "to dwell" (https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.27.4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B4%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B4%D6%A3%D7%99&with=Lexicon&lang2=en)

But is that a proper name?

These are Levites. Shabtai is previously mentioned in Ezra 10:15.

See also here: https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_(%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99)

Good old Hebrew Wikipedia! Its interesting how all 3 mentions of the name in tanach are leviim

I linked that more for the discussion of the meaning of the name and later references.

It says it might be a name for one who was born on shabbat. But says thats not a likely meaning of the name

Related to this verse https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71491/759

@DoubleAA i fail to see the connection.
