# No Dagesh for Yud, Lamed, Mem with Shva after Hei HaYdiah

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

In general, when a word is prefixed by Hei HaYdiah (the definite article), the following consonant receives a Dagesh Hazak (gemination). Clear exceptions are when that consonant is a guttural and cannot receive a Dagesh. However, in the Bible in some cases, it seems like omission of the Dagesh occurs even in non-gutturals, specifically the letters Yud, Lamed, Mem, when these are pointed with a Shva. I'm wondering what the rationale for that could be? What is particular about those letters? It doesn't seem like it would be difficult to pronounce them geminated.

(Inspired by [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82633/why-is-it-a-sheva-na-in-ha-leviyim) question.)