# Silent sheva after long vowels

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, pronunciation, vowels-nekudot

I assume most have heard about the [5 famous rules](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44930&st=&pgnum=54) of [Elia Levita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elia_Levita) regarding the vocal *sheva.* His rules tend to work well in practice, even the third, much debated rule about the concept of long vowels ([taken](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36865&st=&pgnum=30) from [R' Yoseif Kimchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Kimhi)) – except for a few cases.

This week we read ([Bereishit](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0111.htm) [46:28](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0146.htm#28)–29):

> וְאֶת־יְהוּדָ֞ה שָׁלַ֤ח לְפָנָיו֙ אֶל־יוֹסֵ֔ף לְהוֹרֹ֥ת לְפָנָ֖יו **גֹּ֑שְׁנָה** וַיָּבֹ֖אוּ אַ֥רְצָה גֹּֽשֶׁן׃
> וַיֶּאְסֹ֤ר יוֹסֵף֙ מֶרְכַּבְתּ֔וֹ וַיַּ֛עַל לִקְרַֽאת־יִשְׂרָאֵ֥ל אָבִ֖יו **גֹּ֑שְׁנָה** וַיֵּרָ֣א אֵלָ֗יו וַיִּפֹּל֙ עַל־צַוָּארָ֔יו וַיֵּ֥בְךְּ עַל־צַוָּארָ֖יו עֽוֹד׃

I checked multiple editions, and all say that גֹשְׁנָה should be pronounced as *Goshnah.* I found in *Mikeitz* similar words, where the *sheva* is after the accented syllable, yet no vocal *sheva* is marked ([Bereishit](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0110.htm) [41:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0141.htm#3) and [41:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0141.htm#11) – *vataamodnah* and *chalamnu):*

> וְהִנֵּ֞ה שֶׁ֧בַע פָּר֣וֹת אֲחֵר֗וֹת עֹל֤וֹת אַֽחֲרֵיהֶן֙ מִן־הַיְאֹ֔ר רָע֥וֹת מַרְאֶ֖ה וְדַקּ֣וֹת בָּשָׂ֑ר **וַֽתַּעֲמֹ֛דְנָה** אֵ֥צֶל הַפָּר֖וֹת עַל־שְׂפַ֥ת הַיְאֹֽר׃
>
> וַנַּֽחַלְמָ֥ה חֲל֛וֹם בְּלַ֥יְלָה אֶחָ֖ד אֲנִ֣י וָה֑וּא אִ֛ישׁ כְּפִתְר֥וֹן חֲלֹמ֖וֹ **חָלָֽמְנוּ**׃

I started to think about that these examples are not after a secondary stress *(meteg),* but then I looked up Levita's example ([Bereishit](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0102.htm) [11:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0111.htm#2)):

> וַיְהִ֖י בְּנָסְעָ֣ם מִקֶּ֑דֶם וַֽיִּמְצְא֥וּ בִקְעָ֛ה בְּאֶ֥רֶץ שִׁנְעָ֖ר **וַיֵּ֥שְׁבוּ** שָֽׁם׃

Here there is still a vocal *sheva* (i.e. *vayeishevu)* despite the [shift](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%92_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8) of the accent due to the following accented syllable.

What is the logic behind these exceptions to the third rule? What sources discuss these cases? Preferably, I would like to understand them without the use of the *meteg,* as they are prone to be added as [mistaken](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82633/15256) corrections (e.g. [הַלְוִיִּם](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82633/15256) and [הַמְעַט](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.30.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)).

Comment: Every Shiva after a tinua gedola that is accented (has the taam on it) is not vocalized. I have seen this rule in print, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @Mordechai I thought about it, but why isn't it muted in case of a _nasog achor?_