Dagesh in שישלם
In Tehillim קלז, should I read the Yud in שישלם with or without a dagesh? I’ve seen it both ways.
The “without” option makes sense according to an exception in the grammatical rules of Dagesh application, but this might just be an exception to that exception.
I’ve looked for the answer, but only found examples of the verse in either of the two ways. I encounter this problem every time I recite this before Birkath Hammazzon.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/137015/15256

It's without a dagesh in the Aleppo Codex:

And the Leningrad Codex too:

These two are the most authoritative codices of the Hebrew Bible, and most editions follow their spelling. It's actually quite frequent that in case of a word starting with ְי the initial letter is not geminated despite the שֶׁ־ prefix. See the similar הַיְמָנִי with the הַ־ prefix in Yechezkeil 4:6, although see also the word הַיְּהוּדִים in Kings II. 25:25 and the analogy in Esther 8:16.*
* It is interesting to note that the Academy of the Hebrew Language decided against omitting the dagesh in case of a letter with a sheva in modern Hebrew.

Thanks for your answer!

Do you happen to know why there are exceptions as in Melakhim and Esther, or would that take more than a comment to explain?

@QwertyCTRL It's my pleasure, it also bugged me, especially ליהודים! Please keep in mind that the Masoretes' sole objective was to create a notation for the oral tradition they had with all the exceptions included. The grammatical rules generalising the patterns in these texts are later inventions.
