# Is there an algorithmic way to determine whether a munakh is a munakh legarmei?

Tags: trop-cantillation

In general, a *munakh* before *psik munakh revii* is a *munakh legarmei*. That’s the easy part.

But [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71489/where-is-there-a-munach-legarmei-before-a-kadma) makes it clear that there are others. Specifically, they occasionally occur

- Before *mapakh*
- Before a *kadma* that precedes *darga* or *azla*
- Before *pazer*

It’s clear that I can’t just search for, say, *munakh psik mapakh*, because when I do that, in addition to the three places mesorah says (according to that other question), I also get a false positive: Yehoshua 22:22.

Worse, if I search for *munakh psik pazer*, I get 66 results, only two of which (according to @Double AA) are *legarmei*.

So, is there any algorithmic way to determine which type of *munakh* something is? (Asking so I can make [quantifiedcantillation.nl](https://quantifiedcantillation.nl/) better.)

Comment: From a programming perspective, the list of exceptions is really not very long. It will be much easier to hard code it than to put in what is sure to be a very convoluted algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36788/759

Comment: Note Munach before _line darga munach revii_ is also legarmei like the common case, as is Munach before _line revii_ (with one exception in Yeshaya כה אמר האל יקוק).

Comment: Ok, great. It seems like

- *munakh | munakh revii*
- *munakh | darga munakh revii*
- *munakh | revii* (minus Yeshayahu 42:5)
- all of the exceptions listed in the question I cite and the possible dupe you mention

If that’s it, coding the manual exceptions is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I’ll also add that someone on Facebook just pointed me to https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/User:Dovi/Miqra_according_to_the_Mesorah. The link to the “[Technical Base (Spreadsheet)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkQyj6by1AtBUabpbaxaZq9Z2X3pX8ZpwG91ZCSOEYs/edit#gid=957434826)” indicates whether every *psik* is normal or indicates *legarmei*. The [XML source](https://github.com/openscriptures/morphhb) unfortunately doesn’t make the same distinction.